# Is YouTube live streaming possible with ReactNative?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, youtube-livestreaming-api

It is possible to upload a Video to Youtube in React Native using using Youtube Data API.Is YouTube live streaming possible with ReactNative?

Answer (score 1):

Youtube has RTMP endpoint ( and backup endpoint ) like rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2. 
For rtmp live stream publish, you need a tool ( library ) such as ffmpeg, gstreamer, rtmplib etc. Then you can easily call the library's method from reactnative or native or javascript. Only need to get stream key, then call the method with valid parameters.

Comment: what about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59139063/how-to-broadcast-a-live-video-to-youtube-channel-using-reactnative-in-ios-androi

Answer (score 1):

[react-native-live-stream](https://github.com/wonday/react-native-live-stream) is available,

Install :

```
npm install react-native-live-stream --save
```

> Sample Code:

```
import {LivePlayer} from "react-native-live-stream";
<LivePlayer
    source={{ uri: 'rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/FOO-KEY' }} //enter your url here
    ref={(ref) => { this.player = ref }}
    style={livestyle.video}
    paused={false}
    muted={false}
    bufferTime={300}
    maxBufferTime={1000}
    resizeMode={"contain"}
    onLoading={() => { console.log('loading...') }}
    onLoad={() => { console.log('onLoad') }}
    onEnd={() => { }}
/>
```

Comment: what about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59139063/how-to-broadcast-a-live-video-to-youtube-channel-using-reactnative-in-ios-androi