# How to broadcast a live video to YouTube channel using ReactNative in Ios/Android?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase, youtube-livestreaming-api

Is it possible to broadcast a live video to YouTube channel using ReactNative in Ios/Android?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this library

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-nodemediaclient
https://github.com/NodeMedia/react-native-nodemediaclient

```
import {  NodeCameraView } from 'react-native-nodemediaclient';

......

<NodeCameraView 
  style={{ height: 400 }}
  ref={(vb) => { this.vb = vb }}
  outputUrl = {"rtmp://192.168.0.10/live/stream"}//   out put to youTube 
  camera={{ cameraId: 1, cameraFrontMirror: true }}
  audio={{ bitrate: 32000, profile: 1, samplerate: 44100 }}
  video={{ preset: 12, bitrate: 400000, profile: 1, fps: 15, videoFrontMirror: false }}
  autopreview={true}
/>

<Button
  onPress={() => {
    if (this.state.isPublish) {
      this.setState({ publishBtnTitle: 'Start Publish', isPublish: false });
      this.vb.stop();
    } else {
      this.setState({ publishBtnTitle: 'Stop Publish', isPublish: true });
      this.vb.start();
    }
  }}
  title={this.state.publishBtnTitle}
  color="#841584"
/>
```

Comment: How to add a layer from a web endpoint in it?